# Intent to open a specific tab of tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-intent, tabactivity, android-tabactivity

I have a tabbed activity with 5 tabs. Each tab has only one Imageview. On a previous page I have 5 buttons and I want to create an interface such that each button starts the tabbed activity but the first tab which is visible is specific to that button. eg. gallery apps open a specific tab corresponding to the thumnail of the photo and are also left/right swappable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the tab id you want to open as an extra to the `Intent` you are creating. Then in the tabbed `Activity`, assuming you are using `TabLayout`, you can do something like this -

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(getIntent().getStringExtra("selected_index"));
tab.select();
```

Comment: What if we want to open 2nd Tab when activity gets started without login and we have a check at first tab of login which redirects at login screen.

Answer (score 2):

## Try This

1. First activity

   ```
    int page = 2;
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,TabActivityClass.class);
    intent.putExtra("One", page);// One is your argument 
    startActivity(intent);
   ```

   2.In oncreate method of TabActivity class

   ```
   int defaultValue = 0;
   int page = getIntent().getIntExtra("One", defaultValue);
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
   ```